# Ajax post with PHP not echoing data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am posting data with ajax to PHP and in the PHP I am doing creating folder but it's not working. I am getting blank white page.

jQuery

```
$('#create_team').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "create_folder.php",
        data: { param: $('.folder_heading').text() }
    }).done(function( param ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + $('.folder_heading').text() );
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<p class="folder_heading">Folder</p>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="create_team">
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['param'])) {
    $folder_get = $_POST['param'];
    $nest = './'.$folder_get.'/';
    if (!mkdir($nest, 0777, true)) {
        echo('Folders cannot be created recursively');
    }
    else { ?>
        <script>alert('Folder created');</script>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Can you help me what is wrong with the code? also help me with debugging with ajax with PHP as I am new to ajax

Comment: Have you tried `param` in `'` ***single quotation*** like 
`'param'`. in ajax request ?

Comment: When you debug it, what is in `$('.folder_heading').text()` ? Also you'd normally display what the PHP code returned (in your case, `param`) rather than what you sent. That's the only way you'll see `Hello World` I think. Any error messages on the console? Is your PHP receiving the `$_POST` variable correctly?

Comment: When you click the button, if your browser shows a pop up with the text **Data Saved: Folder** and nothing else then your code is doing exactly what you told it to do because the `.done` part of your ajax is only supposed to show a JS alert dialog box with that text.

Comment: @ArJay I am trying to create a folder, I have updated the code

Comment: @droopsnoot Yes I am getting value of `folder_heading`

Comment: I don't think you can stick an `alert()` into the PHP code like that. You need to echo the appropriate message, and deal with it in your calling Javascript. I'm not totally sure, I have to say. As for debugging, `echo()` followed by `exit()` in your PHP code, then console.log() that when it gets back to your Javascript `done` or `error` function.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need these files to be on a server, Directly accessing files from any location on hard drive wont work.

try putting these files in your local server's http/www folder depending upon which software you've installed, it's www folder if you're using WAMP. Then access your main html file with url http://localhost/index.html

In network tab under chrome's developer tools, you'll see you're request being made
to http://localhost/create_folder.php.